# Count Down In Formula Field

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula-field, datetime

Trying to run a count down in negative after the SLA expired based on the priority.
Output should be,

If Priority is P1, the SLA is 30 minute

When case inserted,

`Formula field` should dislay `0 hour 30 minute`

```
    If refreshing the page after 20 min, it should display

        0 hour 10 min

     after 30 min,

        0 hour 0 minute

     after 40 min,

        0 hour -10 min

     after 1 hour 40 min,

        -1 hour 10 min
```

I tried this formula,

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority, "P1"), 
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,"-" & TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "") 
& TEXT(FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
& TEXT( 30 - ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes ", "not found")
```

Issue in above formula,

it is adding hour when minutes formula reads `0 hour -30 min`....after 1 min....1 hour 0 minute. But it should add hour only after `-60 minutes`.

Similary, P2 has 2 hours SLA, P3 has 8 hours SLA and P4 has 24 hours SLA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that the **30 minute** window is incorrectly applied only to the minutes conversion step and not to the **CreatedDate** throughout. This causes the math to breakdown as the days, hours, and minutes steps are working with different relative values and the **hours** step was seeing an hour pass by, literally, when to your timer it should have relatively been just thirty minutes.

With that said, please try this formula which accounts for the 30 minute SLA and displays the time as negative when the SLA has been exceeded:

```
IF( FLOOR( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/48) ) ) ) > 0,
  TEXT( -1 * FLOOR( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/48) ) ) ) ) & " days ",
  ""
)
&
TEXT( -1 * FLOOR( MOD( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/48) ) ) * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
&
TEXT( -1 * ROUND( MOD( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/48) ) ) * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes "
```

## Results

```
When case is created it displays

    0 hours 30 minutes

after 20 minutes,

    0 hours 10 minutes

after 30 minutes,

    0 hours 0 minutes

after 40 minutes,

    0 hours -10 minutes

after 1 hour,

    0 hours -30 minutes

after 1 hour 40 minutes,

    -1 hours 10 minutes
```

## Specify SLA

In the formula, the SLA of 30 minutes is specified as `(1/48)` and added to the `CreatedDate`. Date/Time math in formulas adds/substracts in fractions of a **day** such that whole numbers like 2 means two days and fractions like 1/24 means one hour and so 1/48 means thirty minutes.

## Display Negative When Exceed SLA

We multiple the numbers calculated for days, minutes, and hours by `-1` to give visual effect that the countdown has exceeded its limit per your requirements. Without multiply by -1 then the math would naturally display "0 days -30 minutes" when case created and after 10 minutes passed would display "0 days -20 minutes" and so on and then begin counting up like "1 days 5 minutes" when the SLA has been breached for 1 day and 5 minutes.

Comment: Great!. Thanks for the solution. I have other priorities also(p1, p2, p3, p4). SLA for P2 is 2 hours. So I tried below one, `IF( FLOOR( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/12) ) ) ) > 0,
  TEXT( -1 * FLOOR( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/12) ) ) ) ) & " days ",
  ""
  )
  &
  TEXT( -1 * FLOOR( MOD( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/12) ) ) * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
  &
  TEXT( -1 * ROUND( MOD( ( NOW() - ( CreatedDate + (1/12) ) ) * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes "`

Comment: But it is not adding hour after -59th mintute. Also, After 0 hour 59 minutes it is start decreasing the minute like 0 hour 58 min...0 hour 57 minute...etc. Similary, P3 has 8 hours SLA and P4 has 24 hours SLA.

Comment: My answer was to your original question, you've now changed the criteria of the original problem statement. But I would expect as you've done just change the fraction (1/48) to (1/12) etc. for the SLA desired.